# need Laravel 5 query builder and database help needed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I`m developing Training management project as my second year project.so that it has trainee students recently and past members.among those i  have to filter active members according to the Training start date and end date.(see the database attributes).

[image]

lets think a member joined today and his starting date is 4/18/2017.lets think he will end his training after 6 months 10/18/2017.for these period he need to consider as a active member.so after click Active members navigation in the nav bar these members must be filtered from the others.

Actually i don`t know how to do this can anyone help me to get ride of this problem.if it can please help me.

Comment: What you need? Please explain more. This? `$q->whereDate('start_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))->whereDate('end_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'));`

Comment: No lets think a member joined today and his starting date is 4/18/2017.lets think he will end his training after 6 months 10/18/2017.for these period he need to consider as a active member.so after click Active members navigation in the nav bar these members must be filtered from the others.

Comment: Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: Well, then the solution I wrote is correct. Start date will be 2017-04-18, end date will be 2017-10-18. And if the current date is more or equal
than start date and less or equal than end date, then it works okay: `Students::whereDate('start_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))->whereDate('end_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))->get();` will return all students fulfilling the conditions

Comment: @Autista_z .your command is correct sir,please add it then i can make your it an best answer.thanks a lot

Comment: @Dasun It is there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g. your Model name is Students, then:

```
Students::whereDate('start_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))->whereDate('end_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much